# Count shared column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
--------------------------
| Client       | Unit    |
--------------------------
| Acme         | Unit-2  |
| Acme         | Unit-2  |
| Acme         | Unit-9  |
| Foo          | Unit-5  |
| Foo          | Unit-8  |
| Acme         | Unit-9  |
| Foo          | Unit-9  |
| Acme         | Unit-1  |
| Foo          | Unit-2  |
| Foo          | Unit-9  |
--------------------------
```

As you can see the client `Acme` is linked to `Unit-9` two times. The client `Foo` is linked to `Unit-9` as well.

Same thing for `Unit-2`. The client `Acme` is linked to that twice but `Foo` is linked to it once.

What I need is a query that shows which units are shared and how many times.

So in this case the result I need is:

```
Unit-9 = 2 times shared
Unit-2 = 1 time sahred
```

---

For `Unit-9`, both `Acme` and `Foo` are linked twice to `Unit-9`, so that's why it should display `2 times shared`.

For `Unit-2` only `Acme` is linked two times to `Unit-2` while `Foo` is linked to it once. So they share `Unit-2` once in this case.

---

I just have no idea how to create a query for this. Anyone any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

i think you are looking for this:

```
WITH shares 
     AS (SELECT client, 
                unit, 
                Count(*) AS no 
         FROM   yourtable 
         GROUP  BY client, 
                   unit) 
SELECT unit, 
       Min(no) AS times_shared 
FROM   shares 
GROUP  BY unit
```

Answer (score -1):

This query is what you need, noticed below the other alternatives which is incorrect

This is the ***CORRECT*** Query for SQL SERVER

```
 SELECT Unit, COUNT(DISTINCT Client) FROM ClientUnitTable GROUP BY Unit
```

Gives you

```
 Unit-1 = 1
 Unit-2 = 2
 Unit-5 = 1
 Unit-8 = 1
 Unit-9 = 2
```

Notice these are ***INCORRECT*** Queries that will give incorrect results

```
 SELECT Unit, COUNT(Client) FROM ClientUnitTable GROUP BY Unit
 SELECT Unit, COUNT(*) FROM ClientUnitTable GROUP BY Unit
 SELECT Unit, COUNT(*) FROM ClientUnitTable GROUP BY Client (Doesn't Even Process)
```

Comment: There is a problem with this query. It will never count more than 2 shares, since you `group by` unit. What if `Acme` is linked to `Unit-2` five times and `Foo` is linked to `Unit-2` nine times. Then it should say that `Unit-2 = 5` times shared. That's not the case with this query.